# Most Apple apps wont open on Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari, applications, big-sur

So this issue has been happening for a while now, ever since I updated to Big Sur, apps like Safari and App store will not work. For Safari, I can open it and enter a url, but it will never actually go the link and follow through.

App store will open but just stay blank
Music I can see my previously downloaded music, but I can't search for new music.

I tried doing a back up for a restart but the backup would end up freezing at 74 mb out of x GB.

And for the first few weeks, any time I decided to open a new app, it would take a couple minutes to open, now that issue is gone but the apple apps are still broken

My macbook is a 2019 macbook pro

Comment: Does it only impact Apple applications? If you create a new user account and start Safari there, does it show the same behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried a Safe Boot?

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you’d make a bootable copy of your primary drive, erase it, and reinstall macOS. The easiest, free option to do so is with SuperDuper but it’s not yet Big Sur compatible.

I think your next best bet is to make sure you have some kind of backup (Time Machine or otherwise so you can at least access your old files) and erase and reinstall macOS.

After you have your backup, hold down Command + R on startup to get into recovery mode. Open Disk Utility, select your primary disk (top-most level), erase it, and reinstall macOS. From there, you can access your backup and pull out the files you need.

Comment: whats the official link for the software?

Comment: SuperDuper doesn't work in Big Sur

Comment: You can re-run the installer instead and just target your boot disk when you run the installer.

Comment: I don’t think the OP is trying to boot from another drive. He needs to back up his primary drive (current boot drive), completely hose it, and reinstall. 

Once SuperDuper is Big Sur compatible it would be a good option. https://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html

Comment: Check the answer now should provide you with a solution. If you still have problems after a disk format/erase and reinstall, something else is going on.